# Setting up create-react-app in docker shell only

Tags: reactjs, django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm curious if anyone knows why it's not common practice to run create-react-app from within the shell.

The goal here is to attempt to avoid having to install packages on my local machine per create-react-app since I'll never run 'npm start' on my local machine but rather from within the shell.

The reason I ask is that I know this can be done in Django. Django can be done either way, where you can either create 'startproject' on your local machine, then create Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml file OR you can create an empty 'app' folder within the root folder, start with Dockerfile and docker-compose file, go into the shell and do startproject from within the shell with no problems as long as you have your volumes setup correctly.

This might just be my lack of understanding of how Django dev projects are built vs React dev projects. Or could be just how python image works vs node image from dockerhub. I was able to create a simple Dockerfile (below). Then run 'docker-compose build' then run 'docker-compose run react_app sh -c "npx create-react-app ." ' and this worked, but this still copies over all the node_modules anyhow.

The part that interests and confuses me the most: For django projects we need to run migrations and startapp commands within the shell in order for it to work properly without causing problems. IE 'docker-compose run --rm django_api sh -c "python manage.py startapp {app_name}" '. Where as react works just fine doing a new "npm install {npm package}" on your local machine and a new docker-compose up or build.

Just looking for clarification and understanding. If what I'm asking is even possible/necessary and why

```
FROM node:14.18-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY /app .
```

Comment: I'm not clear why "not installing software" is a goal.  Installing Node isn't difficult, and it's much easier to use Docker to package and run an application that's already been built than to try to do interactive work in a container.